# When Amazon gives me an item's price as a range like "5-10" how do I get the lower price?

Tags: amazon

Amazon will often list an item's price as a range.  As an example, I just searched for "tshirt" and the first item was a Russell Athletic shirt (ASIN is B0007IBYO6), with a price range of $4.99 - $10.00 shown in the search results.  When I click on the item, the price is then listed as $5.81 - $10.00. 
[image: screenshot of example item]

That difference by itself feels like a bait and switch, especially as the difference is sometimes much greater.  I understand that certain colors or sizes will have lower prices than others.   What I can't find is the feature/option/magic search syntax that lists all the color/size combinations and what their price is.  It seems ridiculous to to have to click on all 324 combinations (9 sizes, 32 colors) to see which ones are cheaper.  Worse yet, on items with less combinations, I have tried all combinations, and still could not find the lower price!

So, how do I restrict my Amazon searches to only show prices that actually exist?  Or at the very least how do I see all prices for color/size/whatever option combinations at once?

Comment: Why do you have to check all the sizes? It presumably doesn't matter to you what the price is for t-shirts that aren't your size (or aren't the size of the person you're buying for). No one chooses to buy an XS t-shirt instead of an XXL because it's cheaper.

Comment: All the options shown here are dead, if anyone has a new one please advise :)

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone is still looking for a solution to this problem, I created a browser extension called "All Prices" that lets you easily see all the price options for each color, style, etc. of an item.

You can find it on the [Chrome Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/all-prices/lfeponenpeeefdlancldjldhidjekpdd) or as [Firefox Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/all-prices/)!

Comment: This is fantastic--would you consider updating it for Firefox Quantum?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do it other than maybe some fancy browser extension to iterate through all options.

I'm unclear why they chose to change the price range to "$5.81 - $10.00" after the original listing of "$4.99 - $10.00"

In any event the $4.99 price is there,

[image: Kelly - small]

Answer (score 1):

You can now go the *All Buying Options* page, through the link ***Used and new*** (XX) from $Y.YY at the bottom of the page.

[image: amazon item page]

There, you will see an option to select the *Lowest Offer For Each*:

[image: amazon lowest item]

And you can furthermore select on new items only on the left.

Comment: You must select a size/color to see the New/Used link, and the link is displayed in different places (or not at all) for different situations.    

The browser extension in the top answer, All Prices, sends a tab to this link, (and it makes finding the link much easier).

Comment: This functionality seems to have been removed. :(

Answer (score -1):

If you have ASIN number of the item you can go to asinlab.com, and perform [ASIN lookup](http://www.asinlab.com/asin-lookup/)

in the result you will get item's lowest price

Comment: This site doesn't appear to function when looking up any ASIN and thus doesn't solve the issue.